# Класс выдает не число, а ссылку

Tags: python-3.x, классы

Написал реализацию класса *Vector*, проблема не в решении, а в том, что вместо ответа выдает ссылку.
Например программа выдает:

> "Произведение векторов: `<bound method Vector.__mul__ of <Vector object at 0x7f45d02a0320>>`",
>    вместо "Произведение векторов: 13, 56" (результат взял рандомный).

Прикреплю код, может быть в коде есть ошибка и я возможно не заметил.
Вот мой код:

```
from math import acos
from functools import reduce
from math import sqrt

class Vector():
    def __init__(self, body):
        self.body = body
    def __add__(self, vect):
        self.vect = vect
        def sum_vector(a,b):
                  l = len(a)
                  i = 0
                  c = []
                  while i < l:
                        c.append(a[i] + b[i]) 
                  return c
        return sum_vector(self.body, self.vect)
    def __mul__(self, vector, mult_vector):
        self.vector = vector
        def multiplication_vector(a, b):
                l = len(a)
                i = 0
                c = []
                while i < l:
                        c.append(a[i]*b[i])
                        i += 1
                arr = c
                return reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, arr)
        self.mult_vector = multiplication_vector(self.vector, self.body)
        return self.mult_vector
    def __rmul__(self, numder):
        self.number = number
        def multi_number(a,b):
                  c = []
                  for i in range(len(a)):
                        c.append(a[i]* b)
                  return c
        return multi_number(self.body, self.number) 
    def __str__(self):
        pass
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.body)
    def norm(self, norma_vector):
        self.norma_vector = sqrt(multiplication_vector(self.body, self.body))
        return self.norma_vector
    def angle(self, vect):
        return acos(self.mult_vector/(self.norma_vector * sqrt(multiplication_vector(self.vect, self.vect))))
print('Введите количество компонент вектора')
n = int(input())
print('Введите координаты вектора')
v = []
for i in range(n):
    new_element = int(input())
    v.append(new_element)  

obj1 = Vector(v)
print('Размерность вектора:', obj1.__len__, 'Длина вектора:', obj1.norm)
print('Введите число для умножения на вектор')
number = int(input())
obj0 = Vector(number)
print(obj0.__rmul__)
print('Введите вектор для сложения и умножения с первоначальным')
vect = []
for j in range(n):
    new_element0 = int(input())
    vect.append(new_element0)
obj2 = Vector(vect)
print('Произведение векторов:', obj2.__mul__,'Сумма векторов:' ,obj2.__add__ , 'Угол между векторами:', obj2.angle)
```

Comment: Код скопируйте в вопрос,  отметьте и  <Ctrl-K> для выделения как код.

Answer (score 3):

У вас в коде методы нигде не вызываются.

Чтобы запустить метод и получить результат, нужно после имени метода дописать скобки со списком аргументов.

И ещё - какой смысл переопределять специальные методы, чтобы потом их всё-равно вызывать явно?